# Jupyter notebook 5 Upgrade issue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been running Jupyter Notebook for the past few months, launched from Cygwin. Recently I found out they published a new version, and can upgrade by typing in

```
pip install --upgrade notebook
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work and I am not sure what steps to take to fix it.

I am operating Windows 10 PC, ran this command from both Cygwin and CMD and recieved different errors... Recently I had to install a C compiler for a machine learning project but unsure if that affects the upgrade. The long code below is what was produced from Cygwin:

```
$ pip install --upgrade jupyter
Collecting jupyter
  Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Downloading qtconsole-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 2.1MB/s
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Using cached ipykernel-4.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Downloading jupyter_console-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Downloading ipywidgets-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 2.2MB/s
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Using cached nbconvert-5.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Using cached notebook-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: jupyter-core in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter)
Collecting jupyter-client>=4.1 (from qtconsole->jupyter)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: ipython-genutils in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: traitlets in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter)
Collecting pygments (from qtconsole->jupyter)
  Using cached Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: tornado>=4.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter)
Collecting ipython>=4.0.0 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached ipython-5.3.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-1.0.14-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=2.0.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading widgetsnbextension-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 418kB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: nbformat>=4.2.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
Collecting bleach (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached bleach-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mistune!=0.6 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached mistune-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting entrypoints>=0.2.2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached entrypoints-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting testpath (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached testpath-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting jinja2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: terminado>=0.3.3; sys_platform != "win32" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter)
Collecting pyzmq>=13 (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter)
  Using cached pyzmq-16.0.2.tar.gz
Requirement already up-to-date: decorator in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->qtconsole->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: backports-abc>=0.4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: singledispatch in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Collecting simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached setuptools-34.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached pexpect-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached pathlib2-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Using cached wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
Collecting html5lib>=0.99999999 (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached html5lib-0.999999999-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting configparser>=3.5; python_version == "2.7" (from entrypoints>=0.2.2->nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2->nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: ptyprocess in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from terminado>=0.3.3; sys_platform != "win32"->notebook->jupyter)
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting packaging>=16.8 (from setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scandir; python_version < "3.5" (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached scandir-1.5.tar.gz
Requirement already up-to-date: functools32; python_version == "2.7" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
Collecting webencodings (from html5lib>=0.99999999->bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: pyzmq, scandir
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyzmq ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zWuc35/pyzmq/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpMA8YX6pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq
  copying zmq/decorators.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq
  copying zmq/error.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq
2.7/zmq/backend
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/backend/cffi
  copying zmq/backend/cffi/constants.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/backend/cffi
  copying zmq/backend/cffi/context.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/backend/cffi
  copying zmq/backend/cffi/devices.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/backend/cffi
  copying zmq/tests/test_pair.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/tests
  copying zmq/tests/test_win32_shim.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/tests
  copying zmq/tests/test_z85.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/tests
  copying zmq/tests/test_zmqstream.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/tests
  copying zmq/backend/cython/constant_enums.pxi -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/backend/cython
  copying zmq/devices/monitoredqueue.pxd -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/devices
  copying zmq/utils/buffers.pxd -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/utils
  copying zmq/utils/getpid_compat.h -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/utils
  copying zmq/utils/ipcmaxlen.h -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/utils
  copying zmq/utils/pyversion_compat.h -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/utils
  copying zmq/utils/zmq_compat.h -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/utils
  copying zmq/utils/zmq_constants.h -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/utils
  running build_ext
  running configure
  pkg-config not found
  {'libraries': ['zmq'], 'extra_link_args': [], 'runtime_library_dirs': [], 'library_dirs': [], 'include_dirs': []}
  gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -c build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/check_sys_un.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/check_sys_un.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  Warning: No sys/un.h, IPC_PATH_MAX_LEN will be undefined: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ************************************************
  Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
      Custom ZMQ dir:
  gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Izmq/utils -Izmq/backend/cython -Izmq/devices -c build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  Failed with default libzmq, trying again with /usr/local
  {'libraries': ['zmq'], 'extra_link_args': [], 'runtime_library_dirs': [], 'library_dirs': ['/usr/local/lib'], 'include_dirs': ['/usr/local/include']}
  ************************************************
  Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
      Custom ZMQ dir:       /usr/local
  gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -Izmq/utils -Izmq/backend/cython -Izmq/devices -c build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ************************************************
  Warning: Couldn't find an acceptable libzmq on the system.

  If you expected pyzmq to link against an installed libzmq, please check to make sure:

      * You have a C compiler installed
      * A development version of Python is installed (including headers)
      * A development version of ZMQ >= 3.2 is installed (including headers)
      * If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
      * If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
        try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
        or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`

  You can skip all this detection/waiting nonsense if you know
  you want pyzmq to bundle libzmq as an extension by passing:

      `--zmq=bundled`

  I will now try to build libzmq as a Python extension
  unless you interrupt me (^C) in the next 10 seconds...

   1...
  ************************************************
  Using bundled libzmq
  already have bundled/zeromq
  attempting ./configure to generate platform.hpp
  Warning: failed to configure libzmq:
  /bin/sh: ./configure: No such file or directory

  staging platform.hpp from: buildutils/include_linux
  ************************************************
  checking for timer_create
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/tmp
  cc -c /tmp/timer_createoYrEzH.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/tmp/timer_createoYrEzH.o
  unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory
  no timer_create, linking librt
  ************************************************
  building 'zmq.libzmq' extension
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/buildutils
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled/zeromq
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled/zeromq/src
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled/zeromq/tweetnacl
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/src
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/contrib
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/contrib/randombytes
  gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DZMQ_HAVE_CURVE=1 -DZMQ_USE_TWEETNACL=1 -DZMQ_USE_POLL=1 -Ibundled/zeromq/include -Ibundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/src -Ibundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/contrib/randombytes -Ibundled -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c buildutils/initlibzmq.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/buildutils/initlibzmq.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyzmq
  Running setup.py clean for pyzmq
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scandir ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zWuc35/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpLQng49pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7
  copying scandir.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7
  running build_ext
  building '_scandir' extension
  creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7
  gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _scandir.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/_scandir.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scandir
  Running setup.py clean for scandir
Failed to build pyzmq scandir
Installing collected packages: pyzmq, jupyter-client, simplegeneric, backports.shutil-get-terminal-size, appdirs, pyparsing, packaging, setuptools, pexpect, scandir, pathlib2, pickleshare, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, pygments, ipython, ipykernel, qtconsole, jupyter-console, MarkupSafe, jinja2, webencodings, html5lib, bleach, mistune, configparser, entrypoints, testpath, pandocfilters, nbconvert, notebook, widgetsnbextension, ipywidgets, jupyter
  Running setup.py install for pyzmq ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zWuc35/pyzmq/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-awKin0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq
    copying zmq/decorators.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq
    copying zmq/error.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq
    copying zmq/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq
    creating build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/auth

    copying zmq/utils/zmq_constants.h -> build/lib.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/zmq/utils
    running build_ext
    running configure
    pkg-config not found
    {'libraries': ['zmq'], 'extra_link_args': [], 'runtime_library_dirs': [], 'library_dirs': [], 'include_dirs': []}
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -c build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/check_sys_un.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/check_sys_un.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    Warning: No sys/un.h, IPC_PATH_MAX_LEN will be undefined: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ************************************************
    Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
        Custom ZMQ dir:
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Izmq/utils -Izmq/backend/cython -Izmq/devices -c build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    Failed with default libzmq, trying again with /usr/local
    {'libraries': ['zmq'], 'extra_link_args': [], 'runtime_library_dirs': [], 'library_dirs': ['/usr/local/lib'], 'include_dirs': ['/usr/local/include']}
    ************************************************
    Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
        Custom ZMQ dir:       /usr/local
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -Izmq/utils -Izmq/backend/cython -Izmq/devices -c build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ************************************************
    Warning: Couldn't find an acceptable libzmq on the system.

    If you expected pyzmq to link against an installed libzmq, please check to make sure:

        * You have a C compiler installed
        * A development version of Python is installed (including headers)
        * A development version of ZMQ >= 3.2 is installed (including headers)
        * If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
        * If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
          try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
          or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`

    You can skip all this detection/waiting nonsense if you know
    you want pyzmq to bundle libzmq as an extension by passing:

        `--zmq=bundled`

    I will now try to build libzmq as a Python extension
    unless you interrupt me (^C) in the next 10 seconds...

     1...
    ************************************************
    Using bundled libzmq
    already have bundled/zeromq
    already have platform.hpp
    ************************************************
    checking for timer_create
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/tmp
    cc -c /tmp/timer_create9unKZT.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/tmp/timer_create9unKZT.o
    unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory
    no timer_create, linking librt
    ************************************************
    building 'zmq.libzmq' extension
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/buildutils
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled
    ...
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/contrib
    creating build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/bundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/contrib/randombytes
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python2-2.7.13-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.13=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.13-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DZMQ_HAVE_CURVE=1 -DZMQ_USE_TWEETNACL=1 -DZMQ_USE_POLL=1 -Ibundled/zeromq/include -Ibundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/src -Ibundled/zeromq/tweetnacl/contrib/randombytes -Ibundled -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c buildutils/initlibzmq.c -o build/temp.cygwin-2.8.0-x86_64-2.7/buildutils/initlibzmq.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

This was at the bottom in red:

```
>   ---------------------------------------- 
> Command "/usr/bin/python -u
> -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-b                                           uild-LH27zW/pyzmq/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
> open)(__file__);code=f.r                                          
> ead().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__,
> 'exec'))" ins                                           tall --record
> /tmp/pip-ghAml0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externa    
> lly-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
> /tmp/pip-build-LH27zW/pyzmq/
```

I tried re-running the cygwin setup and installing all the modules that mentioned gcc, (per the 'gcc' failed error) but it did not fix anything.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's an option for you, I'd recommend [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Even though I like pip and manually installing packages, the advantage I see in using Anaconda is that it works with all important packages right out of the box. That's an important point IMO, especially on Windows...

Comment: Woot woot that worked! I do have Anaconda, and perhaps pip in my cygwin environment points to a different directory. Conda upgrade notebook did it. I've never been able to wrap my head around the environment setup stuff but at least I made it through another package upgrade! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the error you are receiving but the command from the install instructions say to use `pip install jupyter` not `notebook`.

http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

This is what I did:

Python 3

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade jupyter
```

Python 2

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade jupyter
```

Comment: Ran it using 'jupyter'... same result :(